# How to fix Close Date query in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, azure-boards

I have not used DevOps since it was TFS years ago and am trying to get good at writing queries again. I am trying to query for all work items that were open at the close of the sprint. I am currently picking up work items that were closed before the closed date defined in the query and I can't see why. Any ideas?

[image]

I want work items in a sprint that are open or were closed after the sprint ended.
I defined: closed date < 4/25/2023.
Undesirable result: I am returning results with closed dates prior to that date.

Comment: Make sure you group your or query, otherwise it will select items based on either the criteria above the or OR the items below it.

Comment: Many thanks! Forgot about that function!

Answer (score 0):

[Using the `[ ]` checkboxes in front of each condition, you can group statements together using the `{=` button above the row of checkboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#group-clauses).

At the moment your logic is split into 2 halves, one set of ANDs and another set of ANDs that's being split by an OR. You probably want to group the first set of statements in one group and the second set of statements into another group. Think of them as `( ... ) or ( ... )`.

From the above linked docs:
[image]